# How to run custom Javascript using webview_flutter package?

Tags: flutter, flutterwebviewplugin, webview-flutter

I have build an app using [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) plugin, now I want to hide a div from my webview.
The issue is I'm not able to figure out how to run custom Javascript using this webview_flutter.
I have read articles on stackoverflow for flutter_webview_plugin but not for this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Running custom JS

It is really simple to do so using the webview_flutter plugin.
You can simply use the controller object as,

```
_your_webview_controller.evaluateJavascript("<Some JS code>");
```

## Hiding the div

```
_controller.evaluateJavascript(
              "document.getElementsByClassName('openAppButton')[0].style.display = 'none'");
```

Comment: Answer is true but you should use `runJavascript` instead of `evaluateJavascript`since it's depracated.